# 'method not found' after using controller decorator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, deface

I'm trying to add a feature to the spree admin page to resend the shipment email.

I'm getting this error,

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `resend_shipment_email_admin_order_url' for #<#<Class:0x0000000668cf80>:0x00000006683700>):
    16:               </ul>
    17:             
    18:   <%= button_link_to Spree.t('Resend order email'), resend_admin_order_url(@order), method: :post, icon: 'email' %>
    19:   <%= button_link_to Spree.t('Resend shipment email'), resend_shipment_email_admin_order_url(@order), method: :post, icon: 'email'
 %>
    20:   </div>
    21:           <% end %>
    22:         </div>
```

Here is my decorator, app/controllers/spree/orders_controller_decorator.rb,

```
Spree::Admin::OrdersController.class_eval do

  before_action :load_order, only: [:edit, :update, :cancel, :resume, :approve, :resend, :resend_shipment_email, :open_adjustments, :close_adjustments, :cart]

  def resend_shipment_email
    if @order.shipment_state == "shipped"
      ShipmentMailer.shipped_email(@order.shipments.last.id).deliver
      flash[:success] = "Shipment Email Resent"
      redirect_to :back
    else
      flash[:error] = "Cannot send shipment email. Order not marked as shipped."
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end

end
```

Here's my routes,

```
  namespace :admin do
    resources :orders, except: [:show] do
      member do
        post :resend_shipment_email
      end
    end
  end
```

Here's the view override,

```
Deface::Override.new(:virtual_path => 'spree/admin/shared/_content_header',
  :name => 'add_resend_shipment_email_button_to_spree_admin',
  :insert_bottom => "[data-hook='toolbar'], #toolbar[data-hook]",
  :text => "
  <%= button_link_to Spree.t('Resend order email'), resend_admin_order_url(@order), method: :post, icon: 'email' %>
  <%= button_link_to Spree.t('Resend shipment email'), resend_shipment_email_admin_order_url(@order), method: :post, icon: 'email' %>
  "
)
```

Here is a snippet from rake routes,

```
resend_shipment_email_admin_order POST   /admin/orders/:id/resend_shipment_email(.:format) admin/orders#resend_shipment_email
                               resend_admin_order POST     /admin/orders/:id/resend(.:format)                                          spree/admin/orders#resend
```

Answer (score 0):

What I had to do was fix my routes file so spree could recognize,

```
Spree::Core::Engine.routes.draw do
    namespace :admin do
      resources :orders, except: [:show] do
        member do
          post :resend_shipment_email
        end
      end
    end
  end
```